# Calling Qpainter's method paint to refresh image and change color

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a object call `Player` which inherits from `QGraphicsObject`.

What I am trying to do is to change the image of the player and the colour of the bounding shape when I click on it with the mouse. The thing is i don't know what values to send to `player->paint()` to update the image.

I override the two pure virtual functions as follows

In player.h :

```
class Player : public QGraphicsObject
{
public:
    Player();
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    QPainterPath shape() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget);

    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
}
```

in player.cpp

```
Player::Player()
{
    QPixmap m_playerPixmap(":/images/images/chevalier/test1.png");
}

QRectF Player::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(-15, 0, 128, 130);
}

QPainterPath Player::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addEllipse(-15, 70, 100, 60);
    return path;
}

void Player::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget)
{

    QPen linepen;

    linepen.setWidth(5);
    linepen.setColor(Qt::red);

    painter->setPen(linepen);

    painter->drawPath(shape());

    painter->drawPixmap(0, 0, m_playerPixmap);
}

void Player::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    this->paint();
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `update()`.

This will mark the item to be updated, and issue a paint event, which will then call `paint` with the correct parameters